# Set Columns selected through input box as variable

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to develop a code to vlookup for values in another workbook (OpenBook_CY) and store it in Comp_Book. The code is working well however i need to change a few fixed columns to variables

```
Dim Conp_Book as Workbook, OpenBook_CY as Workbook   
Dim M_Sheet As Worksheet, CY_Sheet As Worksheet
Dim M_LR As Long, CY_LR As Long, r As Long, SelectE_Column As Long, E_Column As range
Dim CY_Rng As range,

Set M_Sheet = Comp_Book.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set CY_Sheet = OpenBook_CY.Worksheets("Trial-New")

M_LR = M_Sheet.range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
CY_LR = CY_Sheet.range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
SelectE_Column = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select your entity ", Title:="Select Entity", Type:=8)
Set E_Column = SelectE_Column.EntireColumn
Set CY_Rng = CY_Sheet.range("B2:J" & CY_LR)

For r = 6 To M_LR
On Error Resume Next
M_Sheet.range("D" & r).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(M_Sheet.range("B" & r).Value, 
CY_Rng, 9, 0)
Next r
```

I want to replace "J" (as mentioned in CY_Rng) with the column selected by user through input box (which I have named as E_Column for the time being). Right now J is a fixed column however I instead want it to be the column selected by user (In CY_Rng)

```
Set CY_Rng = CY_Sheet.range("B2:J" & CY_LR)
```

Secondly in the vlookup formula "9" represents the 9th column which is "J" as mentioned above
Likewise i want the number "9" to be replaced with column number selected by user above

```
M_Sheet.range("D" & r).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(M_Sheet.range("B" & r).Value, 
CY_Rng, 9, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried declaring Column "J" as a variable?